# "From PDF" toolset not available in 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arctoolbox, arcgis-10.3

I'm running ArcMap 10.3 and there is no ["From PDF" toolset](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-from-pdf-toolset.htm) available in my conversion tools list. Also, trying to use the ArcPy PDFToTIFF_conversion method fails.

[image: "From PDF" missing]

Specifically ArcMap is version 10.3.0.4284

Python is version 2.7.8 (downloaded & installed from my esri portal)

I think my version upgrades on this machine have gone from 10.1 > 10.2.2 > 10.3. I do not have ArcGIS Pro installed, just ArcMap 10.3 Basic.

Am I missing something, does anyone have any idea on what to check or look for?

Edit: found the install folder and it looks like I might be running 10.3 prerelease. I am going to reinstall 10.3 and see what happens.

[image]

Comment: You're absolutely certain you're on 10.3? Per the what's new, the tool was installed in 10.3: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/main/get-started/whats-new-in-arcgis.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_097098A85BE84E878CC3F27AC8AE6096

Comment: Thanks, yeah I am. Added another screenshot. I actually think its the difference in 10.3 prerelease and the true release. I'll update either way.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're on pre-release. I see 4322 is final # for 10.3

Comment: 10.3.1 is out soon there is a BUG fix for PDF to TIFF  http://downloads.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/1031-IssuesAddressedList.pdf

Comment: @KHibma The version was the issue. It is showing up with the 10.3 latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled 10.3 prerelease and installed 10.3 final and the toolset is there.